# Is custom token module sustainable for masive use?

Tags: 7, tokens

Is the [Custom Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) module sustainable for massive use or should I create custom module?

Custom Token will be used for generating URL path, "massive use" means hundreds or thousands of nodes created per day.

Comment: Good question, few followups: Is this one simple token across N number of nodes, or dozens of tokens across N? Also, how complex are the tokens you are creating -- simple text replacement or do they invoke other modules, ex. user? Finally, by sustainable, you're just referring to performance issues, correct?

Comment: The token generates the "random part" of Node's URL, so every generated token is uniqe (it should use nid, user name and some php functions (outside drupal). And my question is intended in general - performance, speed, security... Whatever you could help :)

Answer (score 0):

In general - no, this shouldn't be a performance issue for your use case. The main problem identified with token module and pathauto is in generating the Token UI screen when dealing with a large number of tokens. There are [good discussions on this here on stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/is-pathauto-module-a-memory-hog) but I've also found that using the [token tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) module can resolve most of these.

In your use case case, your using just one token to generate the URL path which is then saved to the path alias table, a table optimized and indexed for performance. The only real demand is on token implementation but this is only done once, when saving the article and you're using objects that are already loaded (ex. $user, $node->nid) to generate it so it won't be a performance issue.